# boost::asio when should I use socket::async_send instead of the free function async_write?

Tags: boost, asynchronous, boost-asio, asyncsocket

`socket::async_send()` is a composed method which is implemented in termos of zero or more calls to `socket::async_write_some()`. However, as the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_send/overload1.html) describes:

> The send operation may not transmit all of the data to the peer.

So, when do I need such a behavior?

Answer (score 1):

When you are bursting info on the socket and part of the info is disposable.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, none of the data is actually dropped - the documentation states "...if you need to ensure that all data is written **before the asynchronous operation completes**."  Some of it may just be sent later.

Comment: "the asynchronous operation completes" = when the user handler is  called ?